# Add unique code to start and end of function in c

Tags: c, gcc, c-preprocessor

I am looking for a way to automatically add code to the start and the beginning of a function. The idea being that i want to profile the running code later. For example i have the functions:

```
void helloWorld(){
    printf("Hello World!\n");
}

void worldHello(){
    printf("World hello!\n");
}
```

I would like to have some kind of macro that expands them to:

```
void helloWorld(){
    printf("Function id 1 enter");
    printf("Hello World!\n");
    printf("Function id 1 exit");
}

void worldHello(){
    printf("Function id 2 enter");
    printf("World hello!\n");
    printf("Function id 2 exit");
}
```

Where the id is uniquely given each time i use my macro. Do anyoen have any good idea on how i could achieve this? i looked at the "__COUNTER__" in GCC but didnt really get it working as i wanted to.

Comment: Have you looked into Gprof yet?

Comment: Fiddling too much with language basics -- like, say, replacing function declarations with some macro magic that adds code automatically -- might look like a good idea in the short term. But people (including yourself) will hate you long-term for it. ;-) Seconding Dave and Downvoter here, take a look at preexisting solutions.

Comment: No, didnt know about it, but i am running my code on a microprocessor, and i am planning on trying to set the id of the enabled functions using GPIO pins and reading and parsing the output on another hardware. I have very strict timings, and cant use the printout ways that i usually use.

Comment: Note that in general, a function could be invoked recursively, so you might need to have multiple IDs for a function, depending on the depth of recursion.  That may be less of a problem in a microprocessor — you're less likely to use recursion — but it is something to keep in mind.  Also, threads will seriously put a twist in your code handling this.

Comment: function pointers might be the solution

Comment: By any chance, are you planning to use C++? Then you can simply create an object of a class right in the beginning of every function. Then use its constructor and destructor for `code or id` generation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If You are using GCC, look at `-finstrument-functions` switch - see https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Instrumentation-Options.html#index-finstrument-functions It basically calls user-defined function upon entering and leaving any called function. This has some advantages:

- You don't have to modify Your functions at all.
- Your code is called no matter how the function exitted (You can have any number of `return` in Your function and don't care)

Comment: This seems to indeed do what i want!

Now the problem is how to somehow create som unique information on which function was invoked, and do it really fast. Semihosting is unfortuantely way to slow. I need microsecond resolution and dont have much memory to spare.

Comment: The unique information You need, is the first argument of the `__cyg_profile_func_enter()`, which is pointer representing the called function. Now it depends on what exactly do You need to do in these enter/exit functions.

Answer (score 3):

you can use the functions name instead of a number as ID. since function name is unique.
for example you can use the macros:

```
#define START printf( "%s:%d Start \n", __func__, __LINE__)
#define END printf("%s:%d End \n", __func__, __LINE__)
```

or in kernel:

```
#define START pr_err(KBUILD_MODNAME ":%s:%d start \n", __func__, __LINE__)
#define END pr_err(KBUILD_MODNAME ":%s:%d end\n", __func__, __LINE__)
```

Comment: Multiple files could each have a separate `static void function(void);` function in it; function names are not necessarily unique across source files (though I think they are within a single file — I can't think of a way of evading that restriction).

Answer (score 1):

It may be more descriptive to use __func__ rather than __COUNTER__. Here is an example implementation of a macro that does what you want.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define WRAPPED_FUNC(funcname, ...) \
    funcname { \
        printf("Function %s entered\n", __func__); \
        __VA_ARGS__ \
        printf("Function %s exited\n", __func__); \
    }

WRAPPED_FUNC(
    void helloWorld(),
    {
        printf("Hello World!\n");
    }
)

WRAPPED_FUNC(
    void worldHello(),
    {
        printf("World hello!\n");
    }
)

int main() {
    helloWorld();
    worldHello();
    return 0;
}
```